# Want python3x to read .nsf lotus notes files and extract emails containing specific words

Tags: python-3.x, lotus-notes

I have email database saved in .nsf extension. Now I want python code to read all emails and extract mails which contains specific words(eg Throw, important etc.).

And can python code also save extracted emails in specific folders based on the words searched.

Answer (score 2):

Python can do this. It's a lot easier if you're running Python on Windows because you can use the [Notes COM API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM.html) - but you will have to have Notes code installed and configured properly on the Windows machine where your Python code is running. If you're not running on Windows or you can't get Notes installed on the machine, then you may be able to use the [Domino Access Services REST API](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp%3FlookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Domino_Access_Services_overview_das901&content=apicontent), but Domino server will have to be configured to allow that.